# setInterval() stops repeating shortly after other process is started

Tags: javascript, electron

I have created an app that tracks the launching and termination of programs on the user's computer and I have run into an issue where the function provided to `setInterval` stops repeating shortly after a program is launched and a notification is displayed.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const parser = require('table-parser');
const proc = require("process");
const notifier = require('electron-notifications');

const {app} = require('electron');
var runningPrograms = new Set();
var firstRun = true;

// Gets the currently running programs and converts them to JSON
function getProcesses(filter, callback) {
    exec("tasklist", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if(err) {
            callback(true, stderr);
        } else {
            // Convert stdout to json
            const json = parser.parse(stdout);
            json.splice(0, 1); // Take of bogus top row of stdout
            const result = [];
            // Loop over the output and convert it into an array
            for (var c in json) {
                const process = json[c];
                const obj = {
                    name: process["Name"][0], // "abc.exe"
                    pid: process["Name"][1],
                    type: process["Session"][0] // "Services", "Console", "Process" et.c
                };
                // Only add processes that the filter accepts
                if(filter(obj)) result.push(obj);
            }
            callback(false, result);
        }
    });
}

// Displays a notification
function showNotification(msg) {
    console.log("Notification: " + msg);
    notifier.notify("App", {
        message: msg,
        buttons: ["Add", "Ignore"],
    });
}

function onProgramLaunch(process) {
    if(!firstRun) showNotification(process.name + " launched");
}

function onProgramTermination(process) {
    if(!firstRun) showNotification(process.name + " terminated");
}

var runCounter = 0;

// Gets running processes and compares them to those that were running last time we checked
function run() {
    console.log("Run " + ++runCounter);
    getProcesses(function(obj) {
        // Ensure the process is not a system process
        return obj.type != "Services" && obj.type != "Process" && obj.pid != proc.pid;
    }, function(err, data) {
        console.log("-> Got processes");
        if(err) {
            // Log error and return
            console.log("ERROR: ");
            console.log(data);
            return;
        } else console.log("-> No error");
        // This set will contain references to all running programs
        const newSet = new Set();
        for(var c in data) {
            const process = data[c];
            // Sets do stop duplication but the if-statement is useful anyway
            if(!newSet.has(process.name)) {
                newSet.add(process.name);
                // Check if the program was running last time we checked
                if (!runningPrograms.has(process.name)) onProgramLaunch(process);
            }
        }
        console.log("-> Made new set");
        for(var process in runningPrograms) {
            // Check if the program was running last time we checked and isn't now
            if(!newSet.has(process.name)) onProgramTermination(process);
        }
        console.log("-> Checked old set");
        firstRun = false;
        runningPrograms = newSet;
        console.log("-> Assigned old set to new set");
    });
    console.log("-> Returning");
}

// Once the app is loaded, execute "run" every 2 seconds
app.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(run, 2000);
});
```

Terminal output:

```
$ electron --debug=5858 .

Run 1
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set
Run 2
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
Notification: atom.exe launched
Notification: Update.exe launched
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set
Run 3
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set
Run 4
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set
Run 5
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set
Run 6
-> Returning
-> Got processes
-> No error
-> Made new set
-> Checked old set
-> Assigned old set to new set

$
```

As you can see, it detected that I launched Atom, and showed the notification, but once the notification disappears the app terminates (it may be to-do with the notification disappearing). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Want to know as well. Did you ever get an answer to this?